# stored procedure

Tags: mysql, debugging, stored-procedures, innodb

i wanted to know if there is a possibility to debug stored procedures in mysql..engine type = InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

You can [enable logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/log-tables.html) and examine the queries in the log. You can also run individual queries from the stored procedures yourself to examine the results.